# Combining registration and login on one page fails

Tags: forms, apache, symfony, twig

I want to have the registration and the login form on the home page of my website, [as it can be found all around the internet](http://www.google.de/search?q=registration+and+login+form&tbm=isch).

So I am having my Symfony2 webapp with the FOSUserBundle, which is properly integrated into my webapp; if I go via `/register` and `/login` it works fine.

But as mentioned above, I want to take both forms on one page.

So I did

```
{% extends "FOSUserBundle::layout.html.twig" %}

{% block fos_user_content %}

{{ render(controller('FOSUserBundle:Security:login')) }}
{{ render(controller('FOSUserBundle:Registration:register')) }}

{% endblock fos_user_content %}
```

This seems to work on the first view. But when I wait for the page to finish loading I get a crash notification from Apache.

**Logfiles:**

- Apache error log: https://gist.github.com/dialogik/501abc2c9f6b9a62ad59#file-apache_error-log
- Symfony dev log: https://gist.github.com/dialogik/501abc2c9f6b9a62ad59/#file-symfony_dev-log

I tried to create a "blank" twig template where I add the forms manually (either by the FormBuilder or directly hard coded into the twig template), but then I get problems because of the CSRF and the form handler doesn't spot my inputs.

My questions:

- How would you try to implement this? Would you call the Controller somewhere else, that in the twig template?
- What might the problem be? Should I avoid putting both forms on one page?
- What exactly causes Apache to crash?

Comment: it looks like there is an infinite loop of listener calls. when you create your own templates with **all** the form fields does it crash?

Comment: No, it doesn't crash. But it won't use the inputs made by the user. So it doesn't work creating the forms manually.

Comment: It won't use the fields for both the registration and login form? do they have the correct names? does the **Request** object have them? try debugging a little..

Comment: No I mean if I manually create a form with exact the correct field names, and if I now enter my credentials (under `/` and click submit, instead of checking the authorization it shows the login form of `/login` with empty input fields...